# Display query result into views

Tags: python, web2py

I queried data from a database. There's a field using the sum() function which I can't display on view.

I have changed the key corresponding to the dict, but it still doesn't work.
When I just print the dict it show me this.

```
<Row {'indata': {'nation': '\xe0\xb8\x88\xe0\xb8\xb5\xe0\xb8\x99'}, '_extra': {'SUM(`indata`.`quan`)': 14635.0}}>
```

So if I could access item.indata.nation to get to \xe0\xb8\x88\xe0\xb8\xb5\xe0\xb8\x99
I should be able to access 14635.0 from

item._extra.SUM(`indata`.`quan`) but it doesn't work

Here's the controller:

```
def byNation():
    indata = db((db.indata.date>=request.args[0])&
        (db.indata.date<=request.args[1])&(db.indata.quan!=0)
        ).select(db.indata.nation,db.indata.quan.sum(),
        groupby=db.indata.nation,orderby=~db.indata.quan.sum())
    outdata = db((db.outdata.date>=request.args[0])&
        (db.outdata.date<=request.args[1])&(db.outdata.quan!=0)
        ).select(db.outdata.nation,db.outdata.quan.sum(),
        groupby=db.outdata.nation,orderby=~db.outdata.quan.sum())
    return locals()
```

Here's the view:

```
{{for item in indata:}}
{{=item.indata.nation}}#This line doing fine
{{=item._extra.SUM(`indata`.`quan`)}}#This line not how could I access it ??
{{pass}}
```

It causes invalid syntax at:

```
response.write(item._extra.SUM(`indata`.quan`))
```

This shouldn't happen.

Comment: item['_extra']['SUM(`indata`.`quan`)'] try like this @Jirawat

Comment: Nope doesn't work still has exception <type 'exceptions.KeyError'>('SUM(indata.quan)')

Comment: please check type of item in loop. either it is a dictionary or anything else ?

Comment: It's working now so I just using the built-in function of dictionary
like this 
{{=int(item._extra.values()[0])}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to explicitly access the `._extra` key -- instead you can simply do:

```
item['SUM(`indata`.`quan`)']
```

However, the above key may be specific to the particular database being used (it is simply the exact query expression used by the database to calculate the sum). So, it is better to use the method recommended in the documentation:

```
def byNation():
    indata_sum = db.indata.quan.sum()
    indata = db((db.indata.date>=request.args[0])&
    (db.indata.date<=request.args[1])&(db.indata.quan!=0)
    ).select(db.indata.nation,indata_sum,
    groupby=db.indata.nation,orderby=~indata_sum)
    ...
    return locals()
```

Then in the view:

```
{{=item[indata_sum]}}
```

See http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#sum-avg-min-max-and-len (and [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/web2py/WAw9Z97HJjU/b4XRX2w3xu8J) for a little more regarding implementation details).